# Looking for Recommendation on Windows Forms .Net Resizing Component

Tags: .net, winforms, resize, screen-resolution

By default windows forms resize logic is limited--anchoring and docking. In the past I've rolled my own custom resize logic when required. However, I'm getting started on a project that has a large number of very complex forms that must auto-resize to different resolutions.  I don't care to invest a ton of time in resize logic.

I see that there are companies selling components that advertise uniform resizing.  Does anyone have any experience with any resizing components/have any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a component [.net resize](http://www.soft-group.it/net/index.php?c=3a&id=11&pagina=3) which seems to work really well.  Simply drop it on the form and it makes the form completely resizable.  Unfortunately, at $178 a seat it's a bit on the expensive side.

Comment: I'm sure $178 is far less than the cost of writing your own

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)? It should allow you have different "cells" each containing a single UI element and have all the cells grow at the same rate.

Answer (score 2):

Aye, TableLayoutPanel and setting AutoSize to True on the form can be quite powerful, but it takes a bit to understand what is going on, but if you have a few hours to get used to it, you can make some awesome dialogs without having to do a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to buy anything and the TableLayoutPanel is not good enough for your needs (which would mean you have some very special needs), you could always create a component yourself to manage the resize, which could work for all your forms. (a bit like .net resize you described above)

You could also take into calculation the time it would require you to create something that does the same work as .net resize. If the time versus cost seems similar, depending on your deadlines, you might prefer to code it yourself so you have full control.